# What is the correct writing of Tcl_cmdDeleteProc?

Tags: c++, tcl

I am learning how to extend TCL with C++ and when I came to create new commands with the tcl.h library i found following example, it implements two new commands "Hola" and "Media". The first just print Hola Mundo (spanish for Hello Word) on the screen the second calculate the average of a set of numbers:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <tcl.h> 
#include <tk.h>

/* Functions prototypes: */

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interprete);

int hola (ClientData clientdata,Tcl_Interp *interprete,int argc,char *argv[]); 
int media (ClientData clientdata,Tcl_Interp *interprete,int argc,char *argv[]);


void main (int argc,char *argv[]) 
{ 
Tk_Main(argc,argv,Tcl_AppInit); 
} 

/* Tk_Main creates interprete before calling  Tcl_AppInit and then passing it as parameter */ 

int Tcl_AppInit(Tcl_Interp *interprete) 
{ 

/*Intialazing Tcl:*/ 

if(Tcl_Init(interprete)==TCL_ERROR) 
{ 
fprintf(stderr,"Error en la inicialización de Tcl.\n"); 
return TCL_ERROR; 
} 

/*Initialaizing Tk: */ 
if(Tk_Init(interprete)==TCL_ERROR) 
{ 
fprintf(stderr,"Error en la inicialización de Tk.\n"); 
return TCL_ERROR; 
}

/* New commands definitions: */ 
Tcl_CreateCommand(interprete,"hola",hola,(ClientData)NULL, 
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL); 
Tcl_CreateCommand(interprete,"media",media,(ClientData)NULL, 
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL); 

return TCL_OK; 
} 

/* command implementation */ 
int hola (ClientData clientdata,Tcl_Interp *interprete,int argc,char *argv[]) 
{ 
printf("\n\n¡Hola Mundo!!!\n\n"); 
return TCL_OK; 
} 
int media (ClientData clientdata,Tcl_Interp *interprete,int argc,char *argv[]) 
{ 
int elementos; 
double numero; 
double suma; 
int i; 
char **valores; 
char resultado[20];

/* Take data list in argv[1] and use single components: */ 
Tcl_SplitList(interprete,argv[1],&elementos,&valores); 
for(suma=0,i=0;i<elementos;i++) 
{ 
if(Tcl_GetDouble(interprete,valores[i],&numero)==TCL_ERROR) 
{ 
Tcl_SetResult(interprete,"Error en los parámetros",TCL_STATIC); 
return TCL_ERROR; 
} 
suma+=numero; 
} 
sprintf(resultado,"%f",suma/elementos); 
Tcl_SetResult(interprete,resultado,TCL_VOLATILE); 
return TCL_OK; 
}
```

The example seems old for me and from an Borland programer (because of the Void Main). When I tried to compile I got two errors on the new command definitions.

```
  /* New commands definitions: */ 
Tcl_CreateCommand(interprete,"hola",hola,(ClientData)NULL, 
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL); 
Tcl_CreateCommand(interprete,"media",media,(ClientData)NULL, 
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL);
```

I get errors on

```
(ClientData)NULL
```

and

```
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL
```

After reading the Tcl manual I managed to change:

```
(ClientData)NULL to ClientData(NULL)
```

and it solved the first error but the second keep on giving error.

The errors:

For

```
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL --> not valid type conversion -fpermissive
```

For

```
Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *(NULL) --> needed primary expresion before token
```

For just typing NULL

```
NULL --> not valid type conversion
```

My question are: Am i writting it wrong? do I have to define Tcl_CmdDeleteProc s type?

I am compiling without flags, just "g++ -Wall name.cc -o name.o"

Comment: Tcl is a _C_ library; you'll need to use C idioms when working with it in a few places. The return type of `main` doesn't matter because `Tk_Main` never returns.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `Tcl_CmdDeleteProc` is a typedef for a function type. Function types have somewhat restrictive rules about what you can do with them.

The code:

```cpp
Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *(NULL)
```

is *completely* wrong, as it is just a parse error. The code:

```cpp
(Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL
```

is correct, but it's a C-style [explicit cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) and your compiler is set to complain about those without the `-fpermissive` flag set. For C++, you probably want a [static cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast):

```cpp
static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>(nullptr)
```

(If you're using an older C++, use `NULL` instead of `nullptr`.)

Comment: I used the  `-fpermissive` flag with:  `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>(NULL)` and it worked. I am getting just a warning. For the   `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>(nullptr)` the compiler says it is a keyword in C++11 and additionally it wasn't defined in the scope

Comment: You need `-fpermissive` to make `static_cast<…>(NULL)` work? o_O I think someone's set the default configuration of your compiler to “very silly”.

Comment: I take back what I said. It doesn't work. I just had a makefile mistake which masked the first one. What I get using your advice:
Always using the -fpermissive flag.
With   `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>(nullptr)`  i get ` Fehler: »nullptr« not defined in the scope`.      With `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>nullptr`
expected »(« before »nullptr«  With `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>NULL`  `expected »(« before »__null«`  With `static_cast<Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *>(NULL)`  `not valid conversion of »int …...« [-fpermissive] `   !but I am using the flag!   Any idea?